# Convert ObjectParameter to Int in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method that uses output from a stored procedure as input to another.

```
ObjectParameter output = new ObjectParameter("IncidentID",typeof(Int32));
_db.InsertInitialInfo(startTime, endTime, output);

//int outputInt = Convert.ToInt32(output);  ---> Doesnt work -  
                                        System.InvalidCastException
List<string> errorList = _db.GetErrorMessage(outputInt).ToList();
```

How do I convert the `ObjectParameter` that has an integer value into an integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Value` property of `ObjectParameter` and cast it to integer:

```
int outputInt = (int) output.Value;
```